# how to sort an array of object within object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have a large array of object with objects.

[[0:1449817200,1:99.21],[],[],[],[]]

`0` is time and `1` is the value. I need to order this by time(`0`) but it is not working. I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/mcuzr/ but it does not work.

I have the following array of object which i need to sort.

```
[
[1449583200000,92.96],
[1449597600000,68.78],
[1449576000000,29.54],
[1449669600000,72.58],
[1449604800000,2.47],
[1449572400000,0.68],
[1449687600000,40.69],
[1449655200000,0.22],
[1449619200000,72.43],
[1449586800000,66.82],
[1449601200000,51.75],
[1449622800000,0.8],
[1449608400000,91.25],
[1449633600000,79.43],
[1449698400000,90.85],
[1449579600000,92.78],
[1449612000000,1.5],
[1449590400000,91.9],
[1449594000000,65.98],
[1449615600000,39.19],
[1449662400000,57.82],
[1449716400000,36],
[1449723600000,0.63],
[1449694800000,2.49],
[1449658800000,70.17],
[1449702000000,0.92],
[1449673200000,0.25],
[1449648000000,0.6],
[1449630000000,68.37],
[1449637200000,67.18],
[1449640800000,2.43],
[1449712800000,70.08],
[1449810000000,0.31],
[1449644400000,2.4],
[1449813600000,0.31],
[1449806400000,0.62],
[1449748800000,0.1],
[1449756000000,71.94],
[1449738000000,0.62],
[1449781200000,65.47],
[1449795600000,0.61],
[1449763200000,74.87],
[1449799200000,90.14],
[1449709200000,1],
[1449727200000,0.83],
[1449626400000,46.81],
[1449741600000,0.43],
[1449766800000,32.19],
[1449730800000,0.65],
[1449676800000,94.16],
[1449680400000,62.4],
[1449774000000,67.64],
[1449684000000,2.51],
[1449745200000,0.2],
[1449734400000,74.95],
[1449867600000,0.46],
[1449838800000,0.21],
[1449720000000,37.89],
[1449824400000,0.44],
[1449666000000,62.86],
[1449820800000,1.82],
[1449846000000,73.77],
[1449752400000,61.95],
[1449885600000,70.85],
[1449705600000,41.44],
[1449849600000,74.69],
[1449860400000,80.92],
[1449946800000,81.99],
[1449828000000,82.85],
[1449943200000,82.76],
[1449900000000,68.8],
[1449802800000,96.4],
[1449889200000,0.72],
[1449896400000,2.4],
[1449882000000,73.82],
[1449864000000,94.81],
[1449831600000,39.28],
[1449835200000,87.17],
[1449759600000,73.07],
[1449990000000,92.25],
[1450004400000,81.72],
[1450008000000,38],
[1449878400000,91.72],
[1450011600000,81.18],
[1449792000000,91.54],
[1449925200000,75.03],
[1449993600000,0.38],
[1449997200000,69.46],
[1449972000000,0.42],
[1449871200000,24.99],
[1449856800000,68.37],
[1449975600000,2.72],
[1449853200000,63.96],
[1449928800000,35],
[1449777600000,88.73],
[1449986400000,0.83],
[1449918000000,1.83],
[1449910800000,33.88],
[1449914400000,78.3],
[1449842400000,59.39],
[1449982800000,46.92],
[1449979200000,80.1],
[1449921600000,0.53],
[1449950400000,80.27],
[1449964800000,75.23],
[1450022400000,93.11],
[1450033200000,84.57],
[1449784800000,76.68],
[1449788400000,35.89],
[1449770400000,78.38],
[1449892800000,90.59],
[1449903600000,0.37],
[1449907200000,41.86],
[1449961200000,71.93],
[1450026000000,82.31],
[1449874800000,0.26],
[1449932400000,0.69],
[1450036800000,92.72],
[1450040400000,71.68],
[1450047600000,94.17],
[1449968400000,82.99],
[1450051200000,0.42],
[1450018800000,91.65],
[1450029600000,0.43],
[1450058400000,0.82],
[1449957600000,94.3],
[1449936000000,81.65],
[1450000800000,0.32],
[1450044000000,2.87],
[1450015200000,38.18],
[1449939600000,74.92],
[1450069200000,76.55],
[1450062000000,84.66],
[1450065600000,0.41],
[1450076400000,84.95],
[1449954000000,0.77],
[1450054800000,82.32],
[1449651600000,0.24],
[1449691200000,91.54],
[1449817200000,0.31],
[1450072800000,74.01]
]
```

The 1st column is date in seconds

Comment: The jsFiddle doesn't match the example you provided here.  It seems you simply copied the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/11352763/218196 . It's not clear what kind of data structure you have.

Comment: Or a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects, but it's basically the same anyway.

Comment: Your jsfiddle console logged an array of objects ordered by value, not sure what the problem is?